# Maps and sets please explain why this code has the output

Tags: c++, set, maps, explain

Maps and sets
please explain why this code has the output
I am especially confused about what m[x] ++ and the out put 3:0
my understanding was that the set is (0,1,2,2,4,4) and m. insert(key,value) would record the map (0,2,4,4,8,8) which would make the output 0:0 1:2 2:4 3:4 4:8 please tell my why this is incorrect.

```
set < int > s ;
map < int , int > m ;
s.insert (0);
s.insert (4);
s.insert (2);
s.insert (4);
s.insert (1);
s.insert (2);
for ( int x : s ) {
    if ( m.count ( x ) == 0) {
        m.insert ({ x , x * 2});
    } else {
        m [ x ]++;
    }
}
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    cout << i << ": " << m [ i ] << endl ;
}
```

actual output:

> 0: 0
> 1: 2
> 2: 4
> 3: 0
> 4: 8

Comment: Please note that you're required to post a [mcve] for such questions. Including the input, actual output and output expected, and probably a good explanation, why you're expecting something else as output.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: Honestly, your code formatting is one of the strangest I've seen.

Comment: The point of a set is that it does not contain duplicated values.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break your code in multiple parts.

```
set < int > s ;
map < int , int > m ;
s.insert (0);
s.insert (4);
s.insert (2);
s.insert (4);
s.insert (1);
s.insert (2);
```

First, you populate a set with integer. Since a std::set guarantees unicity and ordering, your set contains the values `{0, 1, 2, 4}`.

---

```
for ( int x : s ) {
    if ( m.count ( x ) == 0) {
        m.insert ({ x , x * 2});
    } else {
        m [ x ]++;
    }
}
```

Now, for each unique value on your set, you are looking if a entry exists on your map with this value as a key. Since your map is empty at first, you will **ALWAYS** pass this test and never go on the else part.

Thus, your map contains `{[0 : 0], [1 : 2], [2 : 4], [4 : 8]}`

If you had used a vector instead of a set, some values would have been duplicated, and your map would be instead : `{[0 : 0], [1 : 2], [2 : 5], [4 : 9]}`

---

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    cout << i << ": " << m [ i ] << endl ;
}
```

Finally, you print the contents of your map on a terminal. Wait, your map doesn't contains a value for the key `3` !
By using the operator **[]** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), you have inserted a value in the map with the default 0 value in the way.
You should have used the method **at()** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) in order to check whether an element exists in this map or not.